# string representation of DataFrame with max width and ellipsized columns without terminal

Tags: pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` which I would like to represent as string (not in Jupyter, not in IPython) with limited width (for later terminal output), without line wrapping (one value per output line) and with ellipses for excess columns in the middle. This is similar what Pandas does when printing to terminal. Is there a function for that? [`DataFrame.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas-dataframe-to-string) lets me only wrap excess lines (with `line_width`) but I don't see a way to insert the ellipsis automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your correctly, you could just do:

```
print(str(df))
```

But if you would like to specify n rows and n columns, `pd.DataFrame.to_string` has arguments for that:

```
print(df.to_string(max_rows=10, max_cols=10))
```

This would only display 10 columns (5 columns and ellipsis then another 5 columns), and 10 rows  (5 rows and ellipsis then another 5 rows).